# Why og:title not show in Telegram

Tags: html, reactjs, title, preview

Why title not show in Telegram, expect I added <meta property="title" content="test"/>, it only show in twitter and facebook but not in telegram

Comment: If none of these solutions work, it is possible that Telegram may not support displaying the title of a link in its chat interface.

Comment: Facebook has an OpenGraph debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ Maybe it has useful diagnoses. Also the value should be `property="og:title"`, not simply `title`, https://ogp.me/. Maybe that trips Telegram up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.